# Unable to connect android to WCF Service

Tags: android, wcf

I was trying to connect the android application to the WCF service but it's not working. WCF is hosted on the IIS server. I don't know which one is wrong android application or WCF Service itself. WCF service is working fine when tested. Here is my WCF service code.

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://services.example.com")]
public interface IEmployeeInfo
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        Method="Get", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetEmployee/?key={employeeId}" )]
    Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId);
}
```

Here is my android code in which I am accessing the WCF service

```
try {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // http get request

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI + evEmployeeId.getText());
        Log.d("Connect","Connecting to Server 0");
        Log.d("Connect","Connecting to Server 1");
        // set the hedear to get the data in JSON formate
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        //get the response
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        //if entity contect lenght 0, means no employee exist in the system with these code
        if(entity.getContentLength() != 0) {
            // stream reader object
            Reader employeeReader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
            //create a buffer to fill if from reader
            char[] buffer = new char[(int) response.getEntity().getContentLength()];
            //fill the buffer by the help of reader
            employeeReader.read(buffer);
            //close the reader streams
            employeeReader.close();
            Log.d("Connect","Connecting to Server 2");
            //for the employee json object
            JSONObject employee =  new JSONObject(new String(buffer));

            //set the text of text view
            tvEmployeeCode.setText("Code: " + employee.getString("EmployeeId"));
            tvName.setText("Name: " + employee.getString("FirstName") + " " + employee.getString("LastName"));
            tvAddress.setText("Address: " + employee.getString("Address"));
            tvBloodGroup.setText("Blood Group: " + employee.getString("BloodGroup"));


        }
        else {

            text.setTextSize(R.string.text);

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

     Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

When I request the WCF service from android emulator applcation crashes. here the logchat.

```
11-17 22:56:55.566: W/dalvikvm(1174): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-17 22:56:55.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 22:56:55.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1174): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-17 22:56:55.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-17 22:56:55.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
11-17 22:56:55.616: E/AndroidRuntime(1174):     at com.yyousuf.sample.EmployeeInfoActivity.onClick
```

Comment: The error appears to be on a call to `Log.d` are you sure that it is exceptioning in this method and if it is are you sure that in the call `Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());` the exception message isn't null?

Comment: I am using the Log just to find out where error is. By doing this. I find out anything after 
//get the response
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
is not executed. Is my URI is correct.

Comment: Refine your exception handling to specific exceptions that can occur. In this instance if `e.Message()` is null your application will *crash* before you get to print the stacktrace. If you don't want to narrow down the exception handling at least add a condition before you log ala `if(null != e.Message()) Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());`. That way you can at least get the stack trace to figure out where the real problem is occurring.

Comment: I used e.toString(). and i got the following error
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
Should I write network accessing code in a different class. Please point me to the correct source or tutorial if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's an exception being thrown, but because you are catching all Exceptions, you don't have the details. For some reason the throwed Exception doesn't have a message set, and that's why you are getting the NullPointerException on this line

```
Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());
```

Please post more information about the real throwed exception.